# Why won't my 3D model unwrap, even with all seams marked

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers, uv, unity

I made a basic character model, and I wanted to add textures, although I cannot unwrap it in the UV editor.[image]

Comment: what do you mean when you say that you can not? You first need to select the faces you want to unwrap (select all if you want to unwrap all)

Answer (score 2):

When you click "Unwrap", it will only unwrap whatever you have selected. In your screenshot, since you have nothing selected, when you hit Unwrap, nothing will happen.

In edit mode, select the parts you want to unwrap, then hit unwrap. If you want to unwrap the entire thing, you can select the whole model with "Select > All" in edit mode. Now that you have the entire model selected, hitting Unwrap should unwrap the full model